# Removing duplicate rows with condition about other column in R

Tags: r

I need a help with sort and delete rows in dataframe.

Example data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  CODE1 = c(111,111,111,666,666,777,777), 
  CODE2 = c(100,101,102,102,103,103,104),
  VALUE = c(3,5,5,3,2,2,1))
```

I want to remove duplicate rows from column CODE1 and the smallest value from column VALUE.

Result:

```
output <- data.frame(
  CODE1 = c(111,111,666,777), 
  CODE2 = c(101,102,102,103),
  VALUE = c(5,5,3,2))
```

I used code like this:

```
 data <- data[order(data$CODE1, -data$VALUE),]
 data <- data[!duplicated(data$CODE1),]
```

But this causes a random element to be deleted if the largest VALUE occurs 2 or more times. Does anyone know what can I do?

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: While you're working on usable data, please include your expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have *"remove duplicate rows from column CODE1"* while at the same time only dropping the smallest VALUE.

Try these.

All of them include a check to determine if there is only one value in the group; if a group had just 1, then it would always be filtered out (since `min(value) == value`, using the "min" approach).

### base R

```r
do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$code1, function(z) z[nrow(z) == 1L | rank(z$value) > 1,]))
#       code1 code2 value
# 111.2   111   101     5
# 111.3   111   102     5
# 666     666   102     3
# 777     777   103     2
```

Inspired by ThomasIsCoding's use of `subset`/`ave`, here's an alternative:

```r
subset(dat,
      ave(value, code1, FUN = function(z) if (length(z) > 1) rank(z) else 2) > 1)
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(code1) %>%
  filter(n() == 1L | dense_rank(value) > 1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   code1 code2 value
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 111   101       5
# 2 111   102       5
# 3 666   102       3
# 4 777   103       2
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[, .SD[ .N == 1L | frank(value) > 1, ], by = .(code1) ]
#     code1  code2 value
#    <char> <char> <num>
# 1:    111    101     5
# 2:    111    102     5
# 3:    666    102     3
# 4:    777    103     2
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- data.frame(code1=c('111','111','111','666','666','777','777'), code2=c('100','101','102','102','103','103','104'), value=c(3,5,5,3,2,2,1))
```

Comment: why `n() == 1` in dplyr syntax?

Comment: to protect against single-row groups; that is, try removing the last row (second `777`), and then running any of the blocks without the `n()==1`-like logic. The singleton 777 disappears.

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R option with `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  data,
  ave(VALUE,CODE1,FUN = min)!=VALUE
)
```

gives

```
  CODE1 CODE2 VALUE
2   111   101     5
3   111   102     5
4   666   102     3
6   777   103     2
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(data)[,.SD[VALUE!=min(VALUE)],CODE1]
   CODE1 CODE2 VALUE
1:   111   101     5
2:   111   102     5
3:   666   102     3
4:   777   103     2
```

---

A `dplyr` option

```
> data %>%
+   group_by(CODE1) %>%
+   filter(min(VALUE)!=VALUE)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   CODE1 [3]
  CODE1 CODE2 VALUE
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   111   101     5
2   111   102     5
3   666   102     3
4   777   103     2
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the `min` option. My concern was solely about floating-point tests of equality. your code is certainly a little simpler to understand. I like the `subset(..., ave)` method, though, nice.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks. If you have concern regarding the floating point issues, maybe this would be safer `subset(
  data,
  !ave(VALUE,CODE1,FUN = function(x) seq_along(x)==which.min(x))
)`, and other options can following the similar logic.

Comment: ... and that benchmarks a bit faster than `rank`, nice touch (again).